# How to make keyboard behave like in Windows

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm using Czech keyboard.

```
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+cz+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     cz
```

In Windows I was used to use "programming" characters using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (`^`), <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (`~`), and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (`` ` ``).

Because I'm switching from time to time back to windows I need to make it behave the same. Instead of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (`^`), <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+; (`~`) and <kbd>AltGr+</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> (`` ` ``).

It's weird that other characters like `[]{}\€#` work as expected using AltGr + FGBNQEX, but the three above are remapped elsewhere...

Comment: Are you using the same layout on both systems? I am guessing your Ubuntu is using a different variant of Czech than your Windows. What is the output of `setxkbmap -query -v`? Note the "variant" field and check the details of your layout in Windows.

Comment: I use the Czech keyboard, too. The characters “remapped elsewhere” (than Microsoft decided) are available on the keys where they reside on the English keyboard – you might have these characters printed on your physical keyboard. The `[]{}\#` characters are available in both locations on Ubuntu but ``^`~`` conflict and the location of the Engish keyboard seems to be preferred. Compare the [Windows](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_Czech_keyboard_layout.svg) and [Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSsUu.png) layout.

Comment: Yes, I know you use the Czech keyboard on both, the question is what _variant_ of the Czech keyboard you use. There are several variants of each layout, and this is what you probably need to change. Please show us the output of `setxkbmap -query -v` as requested because that will show the variant you use on Ubuntu. Changing to the same variant should solve the problem.

Comment: @terdon Both Tomáš and I experienced that the _default_ variant of the Czech keyboard differs between Windows and Ubuntu in the special characters. There is no Windows layout available as of Xubuntu 18.04. See `grep cz /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`.

Comment: @Melebius There won't be a Windows variant. While I haven't used a Czech keyboard, I have been using Greek layouts for many years and I also regularly have to switch between French, Spanish, UK and US layouts. On the Linux side, we have several variants for each of them (international, dead keys etc). So I am guessing there is a very good chance that changing the variant on Ubuntu will solve this if you can find the right variant, the one that is like the Windows one. It just won't be called "Windows".

Comment: @terdon: Well, a simple check of the `cz` symbols file shows that that chance is zero. Currently there is no exact Windows equivalent among the `cz` variants.

Comment: This could also be helpful: [Shortcut keys that are independent to keyboard layout](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/91433)

Comment: I updated the setxkbmap call output in the original question

Answer (score 2):

You can open the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/cz` file for editing and make the desired changes directly. When doing so, you'll need to decide how important the original symbols typed via <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+{1,3,7} (`!`, `#`, `&`) are to you, and handle those accordingly.

*Caveat pointed out by [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon):*

This will be overwritten by any updates though, so it would make sense to make a copy of the file so the changes can be reapplied easily.

Comment: Hmm, nice! You might want to add that this will be overwritten by any updates though, so it would make sense to make a copy of the file so the changes can be reapplied easily. In fact, maybe also mention `xbindkeys` as an alternative approach?

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for mentioning that updates will overwrite the changes. Added it to the answer. As regards `xbindkeys`, I'm not too familiar with how to use it, so it would be good if you could post an additional answer.

Comment: This seems like the best option, I'll try this.